# How to add extra table view cells to handle user input?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Recently I have been trying to create a table view with different table view cells. What I want to do is that when users click on each table view cell, it shows an extra cell underneath the selected cell to handle user inputs and the extra section disappears when the cell is unselected.

I am fairly new to iOS development and I am wondering what would be the best way to achieve this. At the moment I am thinking of hiding the extra cells initially and displaying each of them when the cell above is selected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a [great set of sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) that demonstrates the behavior you're looking for — displaying a cell beneath another cell when selected. This behavior is used in Calendar when displaying a date picker, and it's pretty much what you've described.

Question: Will each cell have an identical set of options?

If so, I'd consider including the user inputs as part of the source cell and adjusting the height of the source on selection. You can [animate the cell's height changing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates) using `tableView`'s `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. This way, you avoid messing around with cell indices.

Comment: Each cell will have a different set of options most likely. For example, one of the cells thatI am planning to create contains a map and allows user to search location. How should I do it if the cells are not identical?

Comment: Is the set of options dynamic, or is this a static table?

Comment: I suppose either tactic would work — I'd still lean in the direction of altering cell heights rather than inserting cells.